# Strategies for addressing incompatibility issues on the latest Android version

Tags: android, mobile

I'm currently facing difficulties installing my company's application on the latest Android versions. As evident, the cost of refactoring the entire application for compatibility with the latest Android version is prohibitively high, especially considering we've used the same template for all our customers, each with its unique logic.

In situations like these, I'm curious to know how you've approached and handled similar challenges. What strategies or solutions did you employ to navigate such compatibility issues?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.